# MySQL query the same table with two date fields and group by same ID

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I'm having a hard time getting results from a DB the way I need them, this is my table:

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+------------+--------+
| id |      opendate       |      closedate      | openprice | closeprice | sameid |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+------------+--------+
|  1 | 2015-09-20 19:17:52 | NULL                | 10        | NULL       |     20 |
|  2 | NULL                | 2015-09-20 20:17:00 | NULL      | 35         |     20 |
|  3 | 2015-09-15 19:17:52 | NULL                | 15        | NULL       |     10 |
|  4 | NULL                | 2015-09-16 20:17:00 | NULL      | 25         |     10 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+------------+--------+
```

I need to get all the rows grouped by the column `sameid` like this:

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+------------+--------+
| id |      opendate       |      closedate      | openprice | closeprice | sameid |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+------------+--------+
|  1 | 2015-09-20 19:17:52 | 2015-09-20 20:17:00 |        10 |         35 |     20 |
|  3 | 2015-09-15 19:17:52 | 2015-09-16 20:17:00 |        15 |         25 |     10 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+------------+--------+
```

And this is what I have tried so far:

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE opendate >= '2015-08-08 00:00:01') UNION (SELECT * FROM table WHERE closedate <= '2015-10-15 23:59:59')
```

I can get all the rows but I can not fin a way to group them by `sameid`, I tried using `GROUP BY sameid` without success.

Hope you guys can help me

Thank you

UPDATE
The table was designed that way long ago, (not by me) and there is too much information stored, I'm not allowed to redesign the DB schema either.

Comment: Will any of these ever have values instead of nulls?

Comment: curious why you are inserting a new row for both open and close, versus updating same row?

Comment: Hello bingo, thanks for asking and no, null will always be null in this case, rows will not be modified at any time

Comment: Hi tim, its because the table was designed that way long ago, (not by me) and there is too much information stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table format exactly what you describe, then this should work:

> SELECT id, MAX(opendate), MAX(closedate), MAX(openprice), MAX(closeprice), sameid FROM table GROUP BY sameid;

However, I think you should redesign your database schema, seperate open info and close info into 2 rows (they could be in 2 tables or in same table). It's would be better for you to work with rather than trying some workaround.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> SELECT t1.opendate, t2.closedate, t1.openprice, t2.closeprice FROM `table` t1 JOIN `table` t2 ON t2.sameid = t1.sameid WHERE t1.opendate >= '2015-08-08 00:00:01' AND t2.closedate <= '2015-10-15 23:59:59' AND t1.opendate IS NOT NULL AND t2.closedate IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

This will produce your exact output.

```
    SELECT
        MIN(id) as id,
        MAX(open_date) as open_date,
        MAX(close_date) as close_date,
        MAX(open_price) as open_price,
        MAX(close_price) as close_price,
        sameid
    FROM
        `table`
    GROUP BY
        sameid
    ORDER BY id ASC
```